# Changing KendoUI window component property

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-window

I have a kendoUI window component in my page, when my page was loaded it comes up (by default), i want to change this property, How can i do it?

This is my window component:

```
 function initWindow1() {
                var windowOptions = {
                    width: "500px",
                    title: "EGG CHAIR",
                    visible: false,
                    close: close1   
                };

                $("#window").kendoWindow(windowOptions);
                $("#window").data("kendoWindow").center().open();
            }

            initWindow1();
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to change?

Comment: I want when i click on some thing like button my window comes up not by default and as page has loaded

Answer (score 0):

You can open your window like this:

```
$(function() {
    $('#open').click(function() {
        initWindow1();
    });
});
```

providing that your HTML is

```
<button id="open">Open window</button>
```

#### Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/nlGYRVX10Z85yIz2Ts5A?p=preview

Comment: Thanks, but i want a way to prevent window to comes up automatically when page has loaded, by default in kendo window, it come up automatically when u load the page! i want disable this property.

Comment: So don't invoke the function like you do now, remove `initWindow1();` leave one only inside click handler.